# Returned expression type Child is not assignable to type Parent

Tags: typescript

I have a class that extends another class, like this:

```
export class Parent {
    parentProperty: string;
}

export class Child extends Parent {
    parentProperty: string;
    childProperty: string;
}
```

I also have a function that accepts and returns type `Parent`:

```
myFunc(parent: Parent): Parent {
    return parent;
}
```

And when I pass an instance of `Child` to this function, I get the error:

```
Returned expression type Child is not assignable to type Parent
```

I want myFunc to be a generic function for all types that extend `Parent` - how can I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `myFunc` works fine as shown below:

```
export class Parent {
    parentProperty: string;
}

export class Child extends Parent {
    parentProperty: string;
    childProperty: string;
}


function myFunc(parent: Parent): Parent {
    return parent;
}

const foo = myFunc(new Parent());
const bar = myFunc(new Child());
```

> I want myFunc to be a generic function for all types that extend Parent - how can I go about this?

Simple just use generic constraint:

```
function myFunc<T extends Parent>(parent: T): T {
    return parent;
}
```